# Setting Page Size for Pagination feature in Asp.net Core razor pages during OnGetAsync() and OnPostAsync() Method

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I am facing issues while setting Page size while implementing Pagination feature.Any help will be highly appreciated.

I am using partial View for Pagination and Model class for binding.Initially I am setting as default page size and able to get page size value while calling OnGetAsync() method.Then I have a select dropdown where I am changing the page size and then post back happens and able to get the new value in OnPostAsync() method and able to assign to the Model property.

**Now the issue is, when I select any other page index then it will call the OnGetAsync() method again and will take the default Model property value for Page size and I am not able to retain the value which I had selected from the select dropdown and fetching records accordingly.**

I had tried TempData[] variable to preserve accross post backs but it is not helping and could not find a way.Please help.
Below is Code part I am using.

Razor page:

```html
<form method="post">
            <div class="col-3 pr-0">
                <label>Items per page</label>
                <select id="ddlselect" asp-for="@Model.Pagination.PageSize class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.Pagination.PageSizeList" onchange="this.form.submit()"></select>
            </div>
            <div>                
                <partial name="_Pagination" model="@Model.Pagination" />               
            </div>           
        </form>
```

Model class:

```
public class PaginationInfo
    {
        
        public int PageSize { get; set; } = 10;

        public int CurrentPage { get; set; } = 1;
    }
```

Code Behind:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel    
{        
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;       

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public PaginationInfo Pagination { get; set; }
     }



public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int CurrentPage = 1)
        {

            try
            {
                var _pagsize=0;
                if (TempData["PageSize"] == null)
                    _pagsize = Pagination.PageSize;
                else
                    _pagsize = (int)TempData["PageSize"];                
                Pagination = GetPagination(CurrentPage, _pagsize);
            }
         }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {

            try
            {
                TempData["PageSize"] = Pagination.PageSize;
                Pagination = GetPagination(this.Pagination.CurrentPage, (int)TempData["PageSize"]);
            }
```

Comment: `when I select any other page index then it will call the OnGetAsync()` I test with your code,when I change the selected value of `<select></select>`,it will call `OnPostAsync()`.

Comment: Yes, but I want to retain the model property value I had selected from dropdown and need to use this value for fetching the records when I click on any other page index.It should not reset to default value for Page size while calling OnGetAsync().

Comment: So you get `TempData["PageSize"] == null` in `OnGetAsync`?

Comment: Yes it was Null.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Session to store data:

Startup.cs:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                ............
                services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

                services.AddSession(options =>
                {
                    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                });
            }
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            .........

            app.UseAuthorization();

            //add UseSession here
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                .........
            });
        }
```

Code Behind:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int CurrentPage = 1)
        {

            try
            {
                var _pagsize=0;
                if (HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("PageSize"); == null)
                    _pagsize = Pagination.PageSize;
                else
                    _pagsize = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("PageSize");;                
                Pagination = GetPagination(CurrentPage, _pagsize);
            }
         }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {

            try
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("PageSize", Pagination.PageSize);
                Pagination = GetPagination(this.Pagination.CurrentPage, (int)TempData["PageSize"]);
            }
```

Comment: Hi Yiyi thanks a lot for your help.Actually I am using a custom framework library where Configure method is added in that library and I am not having access to it.Other applications also using it.However I had added the changes as you suggested in my application Configure() method and getting exception while running it. "Session has not been configured for this application or request".

Comment: public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        NetLibraryServices.UseLibraryWebServices(services, _configuration);

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
    }

Comment: public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        NetLibraryServices.UseLibraryWebConfiguration(app, env, _configuration);
        app.UseSession();
    }

Comment: Above are my methods with the code I had added as per your suggestion.Is there any other approach ?